# Каким образом можно считать данные из БД?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Имеется простенькая БД PostgreSQL. В базе имеется уже готовая таблица с заполненными данными. Необходимо считать данные из БД, и отобразить через сервлет. Проблема в том что во всех примерах `@Entity` осуществляет создание таблиц, но их ведь они уже готовы.

Вопрос:

- Есть ли аннотации помогающие осуществить конфигурацию Entity на чтение из БД?
- Если нет, то каким методом осуществить чтение?

Вот мой код, для общего понимания

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rs_user")
public final class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private long userId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "user_dismiss_date")
    private Date userDate;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "user_password_hash")
    private String passwordHash;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "user_password_salt")
    private String passwordSalt;

    @Column(name = "user_is_administrator")
    private boolean userAdmin;

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    /**
     * This method returned of user data.
     * @return userDate of Date
     */
    public Date getUserDate() {
        return userDate;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public String getPasswordSalt() {
        return passwordSalt;
    }

    public boolean getUserAdmin() {
        return userAdmin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код - это просто модель - маппинг таблицы БД на Java класс. Чтобы работать с БД нужно настроить EntityManager. Гугл завален подобными примерами.

Comment: Очень доступное объяснение http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скину тебе на примере MySql

```
    UserEntity 

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "rs_user")
    @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "rs_user.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM rs_user v"),
    }

    public class Hibernate {

        /**
         * SessionFactory configurator
         * @param dbUser user of Data Base
         * @param dbPassword password of Data Base
         * @param connectionHost connection of Data Base
         * @return SessionFactory
         */
        public static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory(String dbUser, String dbPassword, String connectionHost) {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure(new File("src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
            if (dbUser != null && dbPassword != null && connectionHost != null) {
                configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username",dbUser);
                configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",dbPassword);
                configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://" + connectionHost + "/ctf");
            }
            else new TestLogger().getLogger().warn("Cannot configuring Hibernate SessionFactory. Use default value");
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    Hibernate.configureSessionFactory(.....).openSession();

    List<UserEntity > v = (List<UserEntity >) session.getNamedQuery("rs_user.findAll").list();
```

Вот как выглядит файл hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <!-- DB details -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ctf</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

            <mapping class="main.java.DataFormat.hibernate.rs_user" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: и за что минусы ставят...

Comment: 1. Это не пример для Spring; 2. Вы использовали проприетарный `Session` вместо `EntityManager`; 3. Вы дублируете property в Java и XML конфигурации;